# Submitting Spark application via YARN client

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I am using the `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client` (Spark 2.1.0) to submit spark a yarn application (SparkPi example). Following are the pertinent lines:

```
    List<String> arguments = Lists.newArrayList("--class", "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi","--jar", "path/to/spark examples jar", "--arg", "10");

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    applicationTag = "TestApp-" + new Date().getTime();
    sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion", "false");
    sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.tags", applicationTag);
    sparkConf.set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster");
    sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.jars", "/opt/spark/jars/*.jar");

    System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
    System.setProperty("SPARK_HOME", "/opt/spark");

    ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(arguments.toArray(new String[arguments.size()]));
    Client client = new Client(cArgs, sparkConf);
    client.run();
```

This seems to be working and the Spark application appears in the YARN RM UI & succeeds. However, the container logs show that the URL for the staging directory is being picked up as 
`SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> file:/home/{current user}/.sparkStaging/application_xxxxxx`. Going through `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client` shows the likely reason for it being that the base path for the staging directory is not picked up correctly. The base path should be `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/{current user}/` rather than `file:/home/{current user}/` as confirmed by the following error appearing in the logs when the staging directory is cleared off:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file:/home/user/.sparkStaging/application_1496908076154_0022, expected: hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:649)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:194)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFileSystem.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:707)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:714)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$cleanupStagingDir(ApplicationMaster.scala:545)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

This all works fine when spark-submit is used as I believe it sets all the required environment variables correctly.

I have also tried with setting `sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.stagingDir", "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/{current user}");` but to no avail as it results in some other errors, such as hdfs not being recognised as a valid file system.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the spark-submit command line tool?

Comment: @Holden The business case requires programmatic invocation of spark jobs. Although spark-submit can be utilised, however, doing so doesn't return the yarn app id (required for app monitoring). Although the spark.yarn.tags technique can be used to query the yarn apps and then retrieve the matching application based on the unique tag, for some reason it seems that the tags never get attached to the application, consequently the app can't be retrieved.

Comment: Just tried, the tags work from spark-submit, however, can't seem to get them work via the ProcessBuilder class (programmatic invocation of spark-submit).

Comment: @WKhattak You can try `SparkLauncher` which invokes `spark-submit` using `ProcessBuilder`, it works fine for everything including `spark.yarn.tags`.